# How to DON'T change name of column while deleting rows

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's consider :

```
df1<-data.frame(1:5)
colnames(df1)[1]<-'Beautiful_name'
df1
     Beautiful_name
1              1
2              2
3              3
4              4
5              5
```

Is there any simply solution how can I delete row from that data frame without changing name of column ?

what I mean :

```
> df1<-data.frame(df1[-c(1,2),])
> df1
  df1..c.1..2....
1               3
2               4
3               5
```

As you can see my beautiful name disappeared. Of course I can save my column name to rename new data frame after deleting but I found it very inefficient when it comes to do it for 100 data frames.

So - Is there any simple solution for that ?

Comment: Just take out the `data.frame` part. Therefore: `df1<-df1[-c(1,2),]`

Comment: It seems that it's not working or I'm doing something wrong, but I'm getting in output vector 3,4,5

Comment: data.frame(df1[-c(1,2),, drop = F])

Comment: instead of data frame with one column

Comment: As pointed out, a subset of a dataframe by rows will return a dataframe and not a vector. ie `df[-c(1,2), ]` should return a dataframe and not a vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the 'drop' argument:

```
df1 <- df1[-c(1,2), , drop=FALSE]
```